# Replace specific value in URL String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a String having URL like:

```
var url ="http://ispeakphone.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2lzcGVha3Bob25lLmNvbS9zYW1zdW5nL3NhbXN1bmctZ2FsYXh5LXMvZ2FsYXh5LXM5LXBsdXMuaHRtbA,,/product/619/form_key/foxmD7jgFv31xmEs/qty/3/?options=cart";
```

I am getting quantity on button click from input as well like:

```
var qty = jQuery(this).siblings('.quantity-field').val(); // 4
```

How can I change this qty in URL String `"/qty/3/"` to `"/qty/4/"` on every time I get new value from input on button click?
I can't simply find and replace because i don't know `/qty/3` exact number its dynamic it could be `2,3,4,5 etc`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Why not rather start with the string *parts* `"http://ispeakphone.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2lzcGVha3Bob25lLmNvbS9zYW1zdW5nL3NhbXN1bmctZ2FsYXh5LXMvZ2FsYXh5LXM5LXBsdXMuaHRtbA,,/product/619/form_key/foxmD7jgFv31xmEs/qty/";` and `"/?options=cart"`, then *build* the new string with the current value every time you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is function for having this functionality

```
function changeValue(str,value){
    return str.replace(/\/qty\/[0-9]+\//,`\/qty\/${value}\/`)
}
console.log(url,4);
```

Comment: http://ispeakphone.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2lzcGVha3Bob25lLmNvbS9zYW1zdW5nL3NhbXN1bmctZ2FsYXh5LXMvZ2FsYXh5LXM5LXBsdXMuaHRtbA,,/product/619/form_key/foxmD7jgFv31xmEsqty/2qty/4qty/6/?options=cart this one not working adding as new qty not replacing

Comment: check it again please

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace method.

capture everything up to `/qty` in `group 1 (g1)`, all the following digits in `group 2 (g2)`, and remaining in `group 3 (g3)`, in callback change value of `group 2` as required.

```js
var url ="http://ispeakphone.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2lzcGVha3Bob25lLmNvbS9zYW1zdW5nL3NhbXN1bmctZ2FsYXh5LXMvZ2FsYXh5LXM5LXBsdXMuaHRtbA,,/product/619/form_key/foxmD7jgFv31xmEs/qty/3/?options=cart";

let desired = url.replace(/^(.*\/qty\/)(\d+)(.*)$/g, function(match,g1,g2,g3){
  return g1+ (Number(g2)+1) + g3
})

console.log(desired)
```